# Bootstrap button highlight color won't change

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

So I'm trying to make a search bar on my form.  However, whenever I hover over the search icon the border on the right refuses to change with the other 3 sides.  The problem is the same for when the button is focused.  I've spent a long time tinkering with the CSS, thinking maybe that the z-index could be the problem with the adjacent textbox.  Needless to say, that and my other attempts didn't work to fix the problem.

Here's a link to the jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/52VtD/6137/

And the code in question:

```
<div class = "container-fluid">
        <div class = "row">
          <div class = "col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-4 col-md-offset-4">
            <label>
              <div class="input-group">
                <span class="input-group-btn">
                    <button class = "btn btn-default no-outline" id = "customSearchButton" type = "button"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></i></button>
                </span>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search SRGs...">
              </div>
            </label>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div><!-- .container-fluid -->
```

Let me know if there's anyway to fix this problem.  Thanks!

Comment: I think you linked the wrong fiddle?

Comment: You're right..fixing it right now.  Will edit soon.  

Edit:  Fixed it, should be good now.  Sorry about that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It appears the search button is being covered up by the element to its right. Here is a solution, just adding 1px margin to the text box:

```
.form-control {
    margin-left: 1px;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/ftfYD/

z-index will work too:

```
#customSearchButton {
    /*...*/
    z-index: 3;
}
```

If you look at http://getbootstrap.com/dist/css/bootstrap.css you can see that .form-control has its z-index set to 2, so 3+ on the search button will make it appear on top of it.

```
.input-group .form-control {
    position: relative;
    z-index: 2;
    float: left;
    width: 100%;
    margin-bottom: 0;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/52VtD/6138/

Comment: Yup. If you adjust the z-index on the button or hover element then the red line shows through, showing the other element is covering it up. Z-index will work if you don't want to use margin.

Comment: After a few minutes of messing with it, I'm not able to get the z-index to work...

Comment: Both solutions worked perfectly.  I did change the z-index on the button to around 1000 and assumed that would work, but it didn't which is why I assumed it wasn't the z-index.  Switched it to 10,000 and it worked..weird!  Thank you both for your answers.

Edit to JustcallmeDrago: I changed the z-index to a high number and it worked.  Try that out

Comment: Updated my answer to incorporate z-index (and WHY it worked). Thanks!